# android application is not getting response from hosted database in the real device

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am developing an android application. I hosted the database and the PHP file, the application works fine in the emulator with URL provided the website to host the database and PHP file. but, when I deploy the application in the real device it is not getting any type of response from the server if it is login or register. bellow is the code sample I have used for the register.

```
 private void registerUser() {
    final String username = Name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = Password.getText().toString().trim();


    String genderString = "";

    //Get the selected gender value from the radio buttons
    RadioButton male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
    boolean isMaleChecked = male.isChecked();
    RadioButton female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
    boolean isFemaleChecked = female.isChecked();

    if(isMaleChecked){
        genderString = "male";
    }else if(isFemaleChecked){
        genderString = "female";
    }

    final String _gender = genderString;



    if (!email.matches(emailPattern) && password.length()<5) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Email or Password is Short",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_REGISTER,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }else if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();
                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", username);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("gender", _gender);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
   //         finish();
    }


}
```

this is the constants class.

```
public class Constants {

        private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://singlover.000webhostapp.com/android/v1/";
//private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.8.101:8081/Android/v1/";

        public static final String URL_REGISTER = ROOT_URL+"registerUser.php";
        public static final String URL_LOGIN = ROOT_URL+"userLogin.php";
        public static final String URL_ADDRESS = ROOT_URL+"registerUser1.php";
        public static final String URL_updatePro = ROOT_URL+"updateUser.php";
        public static final String URL_deletePro = ROOT_URL+"deleteUser.php";
        public final static String urlAddress= ROOT_URL+ "listview1.php";
        public final static String urlREPORT= ROOT_URL+ "reportUser.php";
        public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://singlover.000webhostapp.com/upload.php";
    //    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.8.101:8081/upload.php";


}
```

Comment: Did you declare internet permission in Manifest?

Comment: yes, internet permission has been declared.

Comment: Then your phone and laptop in which you have hosted the PHP page are connected to same network?

Comment: I hosted the database and the PHP to the 000webhostapp and also I connected the mobile to the same network, but I get no response even it works alright with the emulator

Comment: YOu are not getting both error and onResponse call?

Comment: the toast messages shows up empty in JSON response